# Selecting positive numbers from char column

Tags: sql-server

I have a table with `char` column and want to get positive numbers from it.

```
DECLARE @TABELA TABLE (ID VARCHAR(20))
INSERT INTO @TABELA VALUES ('-12'),('10'),('25'),('12A')
```

I tried the most obvious queries like:

```
select * from @TABELA where ID > 0 and ISNUMERIC(ID) = 1
```

and

```
select *
from (select * from @TABELA where ISNUMERIC(ID) = 1) A
where ID  > 0
```

and

```
;WITH A AS (select * from @TABELA where ISNUMERIC(ID) = 1)
select * from A where ID  > 0
```

But they don´t work and returns the error:

> Conversion failed when converting the varchar value '12A' to data type
>   int

The following one worked, but I am afraid it is not guaranteed that it will work in any situation, since I can´t guarantee the order of evaluation of where clause:

```
select * from @TABELA where ISNUMERIC(ID) = 1 and ID  > 0
```

And the other option I thought is pretty ugly:

```
select *
from (
    select case when ISNUMERIC(ID) = 1 then 
            case when ID > 0 
                then ID 
            end
        end ID
    from @TABELA 
) A
where ID is not null
```

**Is there a way to get positive numbers in just one query?**

Comment: Do you want to include `12A` in the result?

Comment: No, only the positive numbers [10,25]

Comment: What if I have  12abc-30defg?

Comment: No, I just want the rows with positive numbers. [1,2,3,...]

Comment: Is there any reason for putting the numbers in apostrophes?

Comment: You mean, when inserting values? If so, no, the SQL Server would cast them to `varchar` anyway.

Comment: OK understood, also when I run the query I get the result on the results tab (in the results pane as such) AND the error message on the message tab?

Comment: Actually, MSSQL will interrupt the processing. Try putting `INSERT INTO @TABELA VALUES ('-12'),('10'),('25'),('12A')` for example. You will not get the 20 value. It shows you the error message and the result it could process.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
select * from table
where id not like '%[^0-9]%' and id not like '%-%'
```

Fiddle http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/c769c/2

Comment: It works (+1). What if the formulae is more complicated, like greater than 10 for example.

Comment: I say this, because your query also returns zeroes (which I can take off using `ID <> '0'`). But more complicated formulaes would not be that easy.

Comment: Well in Sql Server 2012 you can use try_cast function

Comment: In earliar versions you can try `cast(case when isnumeric(id) = 1 then id end as int) > 10`, because case statement guaranties order of operations and you will not encounter an exception

Comment: Or this one, which is the same answer (same idea) I gave using `CROSS APPLY`

Answer (score 0):

You can write a simple query like this to only retrieve positive IDs and ignore non numerics:

```
SELECT * FROM @TABELA
WHERE ISNUMERIC(ID) = 1 AND CAST(ID as int) >= 0
```

Comment: How do I know that `ISNUMERIC(ID) = 1` will be executed before `CAST(ID as int) >= 0`. The query `SELECT * FROM @TABELA WHERE CAST(ID as int) >= 0 and ISNUMERIC(ID) = 1 `doe not work, for example.

Comment: The order of evaluation depends on the optimizer. In this case since you only have 1 table to query from it will evaluate from left to right.

Comment: It is not true for all conditions. For example, if I run the query `select ID from @TABELA where id  > 0 and 1 = 0` it will return no rows, showing that it computed the `1=0` clause before.

Answer (score 0):

Since the @John suggested `try_cast`, I realize I could do it for all versions of SQL SERVER using `CROSS APPLY`:

```
select ID_NUM 
from @TABELA
cross apply (select case when ISNUMERIC(ID) = 1 then ID else NULL end) B(ID_NUM)
where ID_NUM > 0
```

Or like he suggested after:

```
select *
from @TABELA
where cast(case when isnumeric(id) = 1 then id end as int) >= 10
```